# Micro Frontend by Module Federation with react-router-dom v6

Tags: routes, react-router-dom, micro-frontend, webpack-module-federation

I'm start using Micro Frontend with Module Federation Plugin . Now i faced with some issues on building routing between my applications. My Host application have route 3 mfe apps. Each of them have own routing inside. Navigation in Host-app is working, as inner navigation, but when i clicked again nav to hostApp/app1 when I on hostApp/app1/somePage1 it still render hostApp/app1/somePage1.  What architecture you can recommend? How i can control it?Now I use react-router-dom V6 but i want to build application in way that tomorrow i can add another library like angular-router or bla-bla-bla-Router without any changes in host

```
export default function HostApp() {
 return (
  <BrowserRouter>
     <div>Hello, I'm the host app!</div>
     <NavLink to='/app1'> <button> app1 </button> </NavLink>
     <NavLink to='/app2'> <button> app1 </button> </NavLink>
     <NavLink to='/app3'> <button> app1 </button> </NavLink>
     <Routes>
       <Route path='/' element={
          <Suspense fallback={'Loading'}><div>home page container</div></Suspense>} />
       <Route path='app1/*' element={ 
          <Suspense fallback={'Loading'}> <MfeApp1/></Suspense>}/>
       <Route path='app2/*' element={ 
          <Suspense fallback={'Loading'}> <MfeApp2/></Suspense>}/>
       <Route path='app3/*' element={ 
          <Suspense fallback={'Loading'}> <MfeApp3/></Suspense>}/>
    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>
)}
```

MfeApp:

```
export default function MfeApp1() {
return (
    <BrowserRouter>
        <h1>It is a Mfe App1 </h1>
        <Routes>
            <Route index path='app1' element={<HomePageApp1 />} />
            <Route path='app1/somePAge' element={<SomePageOfMfeApp1 />} />
        </Routes>
    </>
)
}
```

Is it a good idea to use in both application BrowserRouter? I see a big issue here when 2 application try to control browser history. But if i leave onle one BrouserRouter in Host App i get error:"useRoutes() may be used only in the context of a  component". That's also makes sense for me because inner app also need some Router to control it. I also tried to use MemoryBrowser and memory history in mfe apps and control path with callbacks like onNavigete(fromHost) and onParentNavigate(from mfe) but I failed to do it with react-router-dom V6. So any examples of working code or your advises will be so helpfull

Answer (score 11):

You don't need to use a `<BrowserRouter>` in the component that you export out of your remote Micro FE.
You can take a look at the setup I have at https://github.com/jagadish-k/routing-module-federation
Including the relevant snippets here for posterity.

In HostApp:
`app.jsx`

```js
export default function HostApp() {
 return (
  <BrowserRouter>
     <div>Hello, I'm the host app!</div>
     <NavLink to='/app1'> <button> app1 </button> </NavLink>
     <NavLink to='/app2'> <button> app1 </button> </NavLink>
     <NavLink to='/app3'> <button> app1 </button> </NavLink>
     <Routes>
       <Route path='/' element={
          <Suspense fallback={'Loading'}><div>home page container</div></Suspense>} />
       <Route path='/app1/*' element={ 
          <Suspense fallback={'Loading'}> <MfeApp1/></Suspense>}/>
    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>
)}
```

In MfeApp:

`app.jsx`

```js
export default function MfeApp1() {
return (
    <>
        <h1>It is a Mfe App1 </h1>
        <Routes>
            <Route index element={<HomePageApp1 />} />
            <Route path='somePAge' element={<SomePageOfMfeApp1 />} />
        </Routes>
    </>
)
}
```

`bootstrap.jsx`

```js
import React, { StrictMode } from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

import App from "./app";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const root = createRoot(rootElement);

root.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter basename="/app1">
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </StrictMode>
);
```

`webpack.config.js`

```js
...
        exposes: {
          './MfeApp': './src/app.jsx',
        },
...
```

In this case, when you are independently running MfeApp, its `bootstrap.jsx` will be used in effect giving you access to the `BrowserRouter`. However when `MfeApp` is used in the `HostApp`, the `Routes` are rendered as a child of the Host's `BrowserRouter`.

Comment: Hi Can I use PriviateRoute with MFE apps? Because I cannot

Comment: Getting error as "useRoutes() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component."

Comment: same here I am also getting this error useRoutes() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are few options how to handle that:

1. What @jagzviruz propose , it's combination between host and remote handling the routing.
2. https://github.com/module-federation/module-federation-examples/tree/master/react-nested-routers - the host is the responsible to update the URL.
3. You can use `BrowserHistory` in both apps and to manipulate the `path` inside the remote app to be always with the remote app prefix ( see example [here](https://github.com/module-federation/module-federation-examples/issues/1986#issuecomment-1205454537) ). I think this is the easiest and understood solution, but maybe not the most effective.